# Using ESRI World Imagery (for Export)?

Tags: arcgis-online, imagery, offline

I would like to download some of the ESRI World Imagery using [this](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=226d23f076da478bba4589e7eae95952) however when I try to add the layer to an online map I get "The layer, World Imagery (for Export), cannot be added to the map". I've tried manually adding it directly to the map however this doesn't work either. I know questions about downloading ESRI World Imagery have been asked before but I have not seen any questions regarding using the ESRI World Imagery (for export) layer. I can't seem to find a way to use this service, is anyone familiar with this process?

In simpler terms, how can I export ESRI World Imagery using its [World Imagery (for Export)](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=226d23f076da478bba4589e7eae95952)?

Comment: What kind of map? Is this using the ArcGIS javascript API? or some other type of "online map".

Comment: Sorry that wasnt clearer, after signing in to arcgis.com the was map under "my content".

Comment: Can this answer be merged with the other question?

Comment: Related: a python code attempt at same (no solution at present): https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/241097/problems-using-rest-api-to-generate-tile-packages-from-world-topo-for-export

Answer (score 1):

As I read it, that service **only** supports export for tiled offline use.

Quoting the map service metadata:

> This map service is designed to support exporting small volumes of
>   basemap tiles for offline use, according to the access and use
>   constraints below.  This map service is not intended to be used to
>   access live map tiles for use in a web map or web mapping application.

and

> This map service is not intended to be used to display live map tiles
>   for use in a web map or web mapping application.  To access live map
>   tiles, please use the [World Imagery basemap service](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=10df2279f9684e4a9f6a7f08febac2a9).

If you want a service to add to a map, you'll need to use one designed (and licensed) for that purpose.

Comment: I would like to use it to export some of the world imagery for tiled offline use. Do you know how I can do this? I was only trying to add it to an online map to try to follow [these instructions](http://doc.arcgis.com/en/collector/ios/create-maps/offline-map-prep.htm) but taking another look it looks like that article is more focused on iOS/Android. See my EDIT: in the original question.

Answer (score 0):

You would have the call the export map method in the JavaScript API, or you can use Python or another language to make an HTTP request.  See the [REST API help docs](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcgis-rest-api/index.html#/Export_Map/02r3000000v7000000/) for parameter information.  This would be for online access.

I am not sure how to make this work for offline access, but if you were to need that, I'm assuming you would need to download the tiles locally and then you could python to query the extents of the tiles to find what overlaps your AOI and export those tiles.  Since this was designed for offline use, it probably says how to do it in the help.