# Exporting ESRI image Tiles designed for Export?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, offline, mobile-map-package

I have been trying to directly export ESRI tiles designed for offline use (http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=226d23f076da478bba4589e7eae95952) to tile package but all the methods I know (Create Map Tile Package georprocessing tool and ArcMap->File->Sharing->Tile Package) fail complaining about layer type is not supported. So I am wondering how I am supposed to "Export" these for offline use.

The end goal is to have some base map in a Mobile Map Package (MMPK) file that includes other data so that crew working in remote areas have some reference about locations.

I have seen the other posts, none really answers this question (or even the original question). Closest questions are:

- [Exporting ESRI World Imagery from World Imagery (for Export) map service?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/142435) and
- [Using ESRI World Imagery (for Export)?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/142178)

Comment: Try this first https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/190966/export-arcgis-tiles-data-to-any-image-format/191623#191623

Comment: Related: a python code attempt at same (no solution at present): https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/241097/problems-using-rest-api-to-generate-tile-packages-from-world-topo-for-export

Answer (score 3):

One method: By exploring the REST API service page and it's sub-pages, especially **Estimate Export Tiles Size**, you can test and refine input parameters until usable results are achieved.

- generate a footprint polygon and convert [Features to JSON](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/conversion/features-to-json.htm)
- Go to the [service url](https://tiledbasemaps.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services/World_Imagery/MapServer) and login
- At bottom of page open [Estimate Export Tile Size](https://tiledbasemaps.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services/World_Imagery/MapServer/estimateExportTilesSize)
- Paste your JSON footprint poly into *"Area of interest"* text field.
- In *"Export By"* select a `Level ID` number you think has imagery for your AOI and level of detail then submit [GET]. (Use a range, i.e. `1-17`, to include overviews.)

  - Follow link for *"Check job details"* and then *"out service url"*
  - if `totalSize` and `totalTilesToExport` are 0 go back and choose a lower `Level ID` and resubmit
- Go back to main service url and choose [Export Tiles](https://tiledbasemaps.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services/World_Imagery/MapServer/exportTiles) at page bottom.

  - Change *"Tile Package"* to `true` and set other parameters as per the working Estimate above.
  - follow on to *"out service url"* as before. In the results are a URL shown as text, not a link. Copy paste that into address bar. If everything worked it will have a downloadable `Layers.tpk` tile package. Download it!

### Screenshots

[image: top and bottom of main service url page]
[image: job status of Export Estimate and non-zero results]
[image: export tiles with text url of ourput]
[image: arcgisoutput Layers.tpk in results url]

**Notes:**

The polygon JSON coords do not need to be web mercator! Any valid EPSG `wkid` will work. They do need to be Esri JSON though, not GeoJSON.

**Don't despair if opening the .tpk shows 'Layers' in table of contents but nothing in the map area. It just means there are no overview pyramids in the package, zoom in several times.**

During the *Job Status* phase 0 percent messages mean that zoom level is empty and you can drop them from the `Level` range.

> esriJobMessageTypeInformative: Estimated Time Remaining: Calculating...
> esriJobMessageTypeInformative: Finished:: 0 percent

*"[ERROR 001461](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/tool-errors-and-warnings/001001-010000/tool-errors-and-warnings-01451-01475-001461.htm): Failed to package tiles"* - probably means tile cache is too large, select a smaller `Level` range and try again.

Theoretically the '[Export Map](https://tiledbasemaps.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services/World_Imagery/MapServer/export)' sub-page should allow exporting a single image up to the max size reported on the main service page (4096 x 4096), but I always got zero results when putting any image size parameters in at all.